# React: Add values from array in another array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do this kind of operation but I don't understand how to do.

I have two array:

`array1 = [elem1, elem2, elem3]`

and a second array:

`array2 = [elemA, elemB, elemC]`

What i would to obtain is:

```
arrayFinal = [elem1:elemA, elem2:elemB, elem3:elemC]
```

How can I do??

Thank you so much.

EDIT:

the arrayFinal is not key:value, but the elem1:elemA is only the first value, elem2:elemB is the second value, for example using a join.

EDIT2:

I make an example of valure of array:

```
array1 = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80]
array2 = [-97:61:-1008; -97:60:-1008; -97:73:-1006, -98:70:-1008]

arrayFinal = [0:-96:61:-1009, 20:-97:61:-1008, 40:-97:60:-1008, 60:-97:73:-1006, 80:-98:70:-1008]
```

Comment: so elem1 is used as key and elemA as value?

Comment: You should provide the mapping logic, should index 1 of array1 used as the key for index 1 of array 2 ?

Comment: what does it mean `elem1:elemA`? Is the final structure - an array of pairs?

Comment: Is it an object you want to return `{elem1:elemA, elem2:elemB, elem3:elemC}` or an array containing arrays - `[[elem1,elemA], [elem2,elemB], [elem3,elemC]]`?

Comment: and what's React to do with all these?

Comment: you probably mean {elem1:elemA} right?

Comment: Thank you all for your answer, I edited the question about the arrayFinal

Comment: be more clear, what youre doing is not valid JS

Comment: do you mean [[elem1, elemA], [elem2, elemB]] ?

Comment: Could you provide an example with real values of what you want?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABALxgBwPICMBWBTaAHgEFE8APKPMAEwGdEAKOqAJxjAHNEAfRMEAFsseVr0R0AnsLgAbAJQAaRACEAfI1kwWxAFyJiAbQC6yrSxX6VJ+foDeiQwGs8kxBwPGriAL6I7AFCIiKx4UCCsSNj40AB0AIZ0dDCcYIxBwf4+ihnBsfnmUMSxgvFojIzxyjDyiAC8akwOhvFeiIXWMMa+8koZ8gDcAT4BARAIdHJ4sbJwnIyomLgEUIyGAIyKAEyKAMymjgAsigCsigBsxr0DQA

Comment: I have made an EDIT2+

Comment: im sorry but your whole syntax of arrays is wierd, you cant use : and ; in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const array1 = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80];
const array2 = ["-97:61:-1008;", "-97:60:-1008;", "-97:73:-1006", "-98:70:-1008"];
const arrayFinal = array1.map((item,index) => `${item}:${array2[index]}`);
```

Comment: this wont even run, since u cant have : nor ; in an array, basicly, this whole question is fundamentally flawed

Answer (score 1):

I See that there is a lot of confusion going on in the answers/comments, some people think you want to combine the arrays into key/value pairs, while others think you want to concat the arrays, while others think you want to make it an array where array1 is the index and array2 is the value at that index.

This is all caused by your formatting of [Elem1:ElemA, Elem2:ElemB]. which isnt even valid JS as far as i am aware.

However you edited your question, and now it seems like you want to combine them like `[[Elem1, ElemA], [Elem2, ElemB]]` in which case you can do that really easily in this way:

```
const array1 = ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3];

const result = array1.map((key, i) => [key, array2[i]]);
```

this will yield the result: `[ [ 'elem1', 1 ], [ 'elem2', 2 ], [ 'elem3', 3 ] ]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! in your opinion there is a way to write like: [elem1:1]

I have done something like this before:
```  [this.timeStampRight, ...array2].join(":")```

Comment: yea, but thats just taking an array and then building a string with it with : between, then it wouldnt be an array anymore, if u do arr = [1:2, 3:4] you will get a syntax error. trust me....youve got me doubting myself and i checked...

Comment: or did u want to convert them to an array of strings? @Jack23

Comment: it is possible to convert?

Comment: what do you mean convert? you simply cant have an actual : in an array, except if its a string, but in your example there were no strings meaning js would throw a syntax because you cant have : not ; in an array

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure both arrays have the same length you can loop through the first one with a map and do something like that:

```
const arrayFinal = array1.map((item, i) => ({[item]: array2[i]}));
```

You'll get:

```
arrayFinal = [{elem1: elemA}, {elem2: elemB}...]
```

```js
const array1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3];

const arrayFinal = array1.map((item, i) => ({[item]: array2[i]}));

console.log(arrayFinal);
```

Comment: this is also incorrect with what OP wanted due to his wierd explanation of what he wanted, yet if u look at my answer here, i converted the 2 arrays into [[elem1, elemb], [elem2, elemb], [elem3, elemc]] and op commented that that was indeed correct and what he wanted

Comment: It was right at a point ;p (at least with one interpretation of the weird syntax).

Comment: Ye, i know but i didnt know at the time caused by the wierd syntax and the multiple edits

Answer (score -2):

Your case is very close to the following utility functions:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zip
https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zip

Also, it could be implemented as follows:

```
function zip<A, B>(listA: A[], listB: B[]): Array<[A, B]> {
  return listA.map((a, i) => [a, listB[i]]);
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABALxgBwDwEEA0iBCAfABQA2MAzlFgFyJYDaAunuVfnfswJR1YBO-AIYBPDA1wEmhRAG8AUIkT8AplBD8kbagDoAtkLTFiQvDG6IAvDIanE2rjCZNuAbnkBfefIgIKcUhUdUjgAc2JUIwYARhwAJhwAZhZEBgAWHABWHAA2FzcgA

If you want a dictionary:

```
function zipObject<A extends (string | number | symbol), B>(listA: A[], listB: B[]): { [key in A]: B } {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    ...listA.map((a, i) => ({ [a]: listB[i] })),
  );
}
```

Comment: this is also not what op wanted, he didnt want to make it a 2d array, he wanted to make it a dictionairy where array1 would be the keys and array2 would be the values of those keys

Comment: ok. sorry. I've edited my answer. Please take a look at the final example. In general, there are no difference between the set of key/value pairs and the dictionary.

Comment: actually, he meant [[elem1, elema], [elem2, elemb]] (i think) OP is really really being confusing tho, and his edits just make it worse and worse

Comment: ive implemented both cases) finally I just do not understand what's going on) just losing points)